# Convert string type to array type in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have table in Spark SQL in Databricks and I have a column as string. I converted as new columns as Array datatype but they still as one string. Datatype is array type in table schema

Column as String

```
Data1 
[2461][2639][2639][7700][7700][3953]
```

Converted to Array

```
Data_New
["[2461][2639][2639][7700][7700][3953]"]
```

String to array conversion

```
df_new = df.withColumn("Data_New", array(df["Data1"]))
```

Then write as parquet and use as spark sql table in databricks

When I search for string using array_contains function I get results as false

```
select *
from table_name
where array_contains(Data_New,"[2461]")
```

When I search for all string then query turns the results as true

Please suggest if I can separate these string as array and can find any array using `array_contains` function.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove leading and trailing brackets from the string then split by `][` to get an array of strings:

```
df = df.withColumn("Data_New", split(expr("rtrim(']', ltrim('[', Data1))"), "\\]\\["))
df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|Data1                               |Data_New                            |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|[2461][2639][2639][7700][7700][3953]|[2461, 2639, 2639, 7700, 7700, 3953]|
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Now use `array_contains` like this:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")

sql_query = "select * from table_name where array_contains(Data_New,'2461')"
spark.sql(sql_query).show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not an array, this is a full string so you need a regex or similar

```
expr = "[2461]"
df_new.filter(df_new["Data_New"].rlike(expr))
```

Answer (score -1):

import

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf, types as st
```

create table

```
a = [["[2461][2639][2639][7700][7700][3953]"], [None]]
sdf = sc.parallelize(a).toDF(["col1"])
sdf.show()
+--------------------+
|                col1|
+--------------------+
|[2461][2639][2639...|
|                null|
+--------------------+
```

convert type

```
def spliter(x):
    if x is not None:
        return x[1:-1].split("][")
    else:
        return None
udf = sf.udf(spliter, st.ArrayType(st.StringType()))
sdf.withColumn("array_col1", udf("col1")).withColumn("check", sf.array_contains("array_col1", "2461")).show()
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|                col1|          array_col1|check|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|[2461][2639][2639...|[2461, 2639, 2639...| true|
|                null|                null| null|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Looks like this will work but when try to write dataframe to parquet file I get error. 
File "<command-1489663418629327>", line 2, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable Please suggest

Comment: do you have missing data like nan in your data frame? if that is the case, I need to modify the UDF to filter out the missing value

Comment: Yes, there is missing values in dataframe.

Comment: I updated the answer, please be in caution, if your df is very large,python udf will hurt your performance, so blackbishop's answer is better in terms of performance